# Issue with conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't figure out why I'm getting:

> 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value'

error when these three dates '011318'; '011418'; '011518' are being converted into `datetime` using `CONVERT(datetime, [Date]) as[Date]`, but there is no problem with '011018'; '011118'; and '011218'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the results for the ones that "work"?

Comment: I *suspect* that even though `'011018'` works, it's not giving you the date you expect. What date is it supposed to be?

Comment: Yes I did. This is what I get for '011218': `2001-12-18 00:00:00.000`. And I just realized it's incorrect! It should be `2018-01-12 00:00:00.000`!!

Comment: This is why you should be using `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a style code, and inject some hyphens into the value to create the `MM-dd-yy` format:

```
CONVERT(date,STUFF(STUFF(YourColumn,5,0,'-'),3,0,'-'),10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
select convert(date, '20' + right(date, 2) + left(date, 2) + substring(date, 3, 2))
```

This changes your string from MMDDYY to YYYYMMDD, which SQL Server readily converts to a date.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because if you convert the date '011318'; '011418'; '011518' they would be interpreted as 18.12.2001; 18.14.2001 and 18.15.2001. Default ist yymmdd and therefore it is out of range, becasue one year = 12 months